# Trouble making an element fixed on page corner (blogger "Simple" template)

Tags: html, css, blogger

I have been using a navigating button to show/hide the bar on right for phone users and small screens.

The website: https://sample-l-core-0001.blogspot.com/

It was supposed to look like this:

[image]

The button fixed to the right top corner, and the bar sticking to the right side.

But after some browser update (chrome), it turned like this:
[image]

I have tried many things, and I have no idea how to fix it. I'm not an expert on CSS and website design, so I hope someone can help me solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its happens because your viewport is set to 1100 and your body width is set to 740px on mobile device.

You can change your viewport at your head tags with

```html
<meta content="width=740" name="viewport">
```

Comment: Thank you, this solved it.